# "[object HTMLInputElement]" al enviar 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, html5

Estaba intentando que al poner una palabra en dos inputs diferentes (después de escribir cada palabra hay que darle al botón respectivo) y que la consola me devolviese si la primera palabra era menor, mayor o igual a la segunda. Pero me sale esto en consola:

```
main.js:63 [object HTMLInputElement] es menor que "cubierto"
```

Quiero que se cada palabra de 1 en 1, por eso no lo junto en el mismo botón.

```js
function escribirpalabra2() {

  var palabra2 = document.getElementById('palabra2');
  var palabra2 = palabra2.value;

  console.log(palabra2);

  palabra2_length = palabra2.length;


}

var palabra2_length = palabra2.length;

function escribirpalabra3() {

  var palabra3 = document.getElementById('palabra3');
  var palabra3 = palabra3.value;
  var palabra3_length = palabra3.length;



  console.log(palabra3);

  if (palabra2_length < palabra3_length) {

    console.log('"' + palabra2 + '"' + ' es menor que ' + '"' + palabra3 + '"');

  } else {

    if (palabra2_length == palabra3_length) {

      console.log('"' + palabra2 + '"' + ' es igual que ' + '"' + palabra3 + '"');

    } else {

      if (palabra2_length > palabra3_length) {

        console.log('"' + palabra2 + '"' + ' es mayor que ' + '"' + palabra3 + '"');

      }
    }
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="input" id="palabra2">
<input type="button" value="adelante" onclick="escribirpalabra2()" class="boton">
<input type="text" class="input" id="palabra3">
<input type="button" value="adelante" onclick="escribirpalabra3()" class="boton">
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir tu HTML?

Comment: Listo, si hace falta algo más, lo pongo encantado :)

Comment: Perfecto, a la próxima aprovecha y utiliza el Snippet para que tu código sea interactivo y todos podamos verlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu función `escribirpalabra3` no haces referencia a `palabra2`, ocupas obtener la referencia nuevamente y guardarla en la variable que usas, así:

```js
function escribirpalabra2() {

  var palabra2 = document.getElementById('palabra2');
  var palabra2 = palabra2.value;

  console.log(palabra2);

  palabra2_length = palabra2.length;


}

var palabra2_length = palabra2.length;

function escribirpalabra3() {

  var palabra3 = document.getElementById('palabra3');
  var palabra3 = palabra3.value;
  var palabra3_length = palabra3.length;

  var palabra2 = document.getElementById('palabra2').value;

  console.log(palabra3);

  if (palabra2_length < palabra3_length) {

    console.log('"' + palabra2 + '"' + ' es menor que ' + '"' + palabra3 + '"');

  } else {

    if (palabra2_length == palabra3_length) {

      console.log('"' + palabra2 + '"' + ' es igual que ' + '"' + palabra3 + '"');

    } else {

      if (palabra2_length > palabra3_length) {

        console.log('"' + palabra2 + '"' + ' es mayor que ' + '"' + palabra3 + '"');

      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" id="palabra2">
<input type="button" value="adelante" onclick="escribirpalabra2()" class="boton">
<input type="text" class="input" id="palabra3">
<input type="button" value="adelante" onclick="escribirpalabra3()" class="boton">
```

Comment: Mil gracias!!!! empecé hoy con esto y ya me había atascado.

Comment: Con gusto, viendo tu código y suponiendo que tu página es estática, tal vez te sería más útil declarar la referencia como una variable global así `var palabra2 = document.getElementById('palabra2');` y luego puedes usarla en cualquier lugar de tu código en javascript por medio de `palabra2`